# why Missing required parameters for [Route: pesquisaavan]

Tags: laravel

error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: pesquisaavan] [URI: pesquisa/{pesquisa}/{ordem}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\1.1.2\resources\views\pesquisa.blade.php)
```

route:

```
Route::get('pesquisa/{pesquisa}/{ordem}', $controller.'pesquisaavan')->name('pesquisaavan');
```

route in html :

```
value="{{ route('pesquisaavan','teste','precoasc')}}"
```

the page without this route in the view works perfectly, so the route in the view will have some problem that will make this error, and I assume I have everything that is needed in the route in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route()` helper takes an array of the route parameters, which has to be named in regards to the route parameters name as defined eg. `{pesquisa}`.

```
 route('pesquisaavan', ['pesquisa' => 'teste', 'ordem' => 'precoasc'])
```